# SQLite сохранение double

Tags: sqlite, android-edittext, double

Всем привет!
Есть база данных SQLite. Поле для ввода edit text. Как в ситуации, когда в edittext ничего не ввели сохранить значение 0 ??? (Ввожу double). Так как в случае, если ничего не вводить, то получаешь ошибку.

Comment: Видимо явно проверить перед сохранением что  поле пустое и насильно присвоить ему в этом случае 0. Большего на ваш вопрос сказать не возможно потому что вы не привели код как именно вы делаете сохранение в БД и не сказали какая именно ошибка происходит

Comment: Добавьте в макете в EditText строку android:hint="Введите ваш текст"

Answer (score -1):

Ошибку получишь, при чтении из БД, при записи будет NULL,если не указать значение.

Два варианта:

1. В самом SQLite выставь Default = 0.00 для данного поля.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. При добавлении записи из самой программы записывать 0. (Как в комментарии)

Comment: Ответ на вопрос нормальный (не понимаю минуса на ответ), оставляй комментарий, если есть что сказать.

Comment: Добрый день. Не знаю зачем вам поставили минус, но так как вы предложили мне подходит.

Comment: Если подходит, то выбирай как ответ. Спасибо.